What is the potential of a conductor between two eletrically-charged plates?
Let's say I have two plates. One is at +20V, the other is at +10V, and they are separated a meter apart.
I place an uncharged conductor that's 10cm wide into the gap between them, 20cm from the plate that is +20V. What is the potential of the conductor?

I can't figure out how to do this calculation. It's clear that the conductor's potential, whatever it is, should be the same throughout the entire 10cm width (or there'd be a residual electric field which would cause induced charges to move). It's also intuitive that the potential should be between 20V and 10V. But I can't see a way to assign a numerical value to the potential, or if the result depends on either of the parameters in the question (the 20cm distance and 10cm width). How does one do it?
Edit: Since this question apparently needs more details. The issue is that if we assume the +20V plate is positively charged, then Gauss's law would give the electric field in between the two plates as $\sigma/2\epsilon_0$. This reasoning seems to hold even if we consider only the +20V plate, so the electric field is still $\sigma/2\epsilon_0$. By $E = dV/dx$, this would suggest that the potential of the conductor is 18V (dropping by 2V, since the electric field is $10V/m$ and we have moved 20cm).
But if this reasoning is solid, then the electric field on the right hand side of the conductor must also be $10V/m$, and there's no way to get to +10V with the right-hand plate. Something must be off. What?

For completeness, you should write: I place a conductor that's 10cm wide and has no net charge into the gap [...] Otherwise there is not enough information to solve it.

I'm voting to reopen because although this question was indeed inspired by a homework-like question, it's not the same and has already been filtered (i.e., I've already changed it to focus on the core issue).

Perhaps it helps to draw the induced charges, like this:

The normal $E$-field component must be equal to those surface charge densities and then you need to assume that the middle conductor has no net charge, so the field strength is the same in both gap regions on all sides of the conductors. (NB: I think it is intended that we use the "large plates, small gap" assumption, only a horizontal field in the gaps should be considered.)
In that case of course the total potential difference of $10\,V$ has to divide in a 20:70 ratio over the two gaps, the right-hand gap gets $\frac79\ 10\,V$ and the middle conductor ends up at $10\,V + \frac79\ 10\,V=\frac{16}{9}\,V$.

How can we know that the potential difference is linear? I'm especially confused because the original electric field is $10 V/m$. Is the electric field after the insertion of the conductor still $10 V/m$? It seems like it should be, because the surface density of the charges don't change. But if so, then shouldn't the potential drop by $2V$ after 20cm?

Potential difference is linear only because that is the solution for infinitely large plates (where the whole problem becomes 1-dimensional) and we assume very large plates. Without that it simply cannot be solved without furhter specification of the exact sizes. The surface density actually does change on the left and right plate, after the insertion it gets a higher value. The field strength goes from $0.1V/m$ before insertion to $\frac{10}9 ,V/m$ after insertion. (Some source has to provide charge to the outer plates to maintain the $10V$ on the total capacitance, which goes up!)

It's not given that these are the plates of a capacitor, however. What if they are just isolated charged bodies? The charge density wouldn't be able to change then?

@JosBergervoet You start off with two charged plates with positive potentials so assume that they are positively charged. From a long way away you "see" positive changes. In your diagram when you add the conductor in between the two plates the charges on the outside of the outer plates vanish and so from afar the system looks uncharged. What happened to all the positive charges?

You are right, there are charges on the outside of the outer two plates and those are what you mainly see from afar, e.g. like this:  https://i.sstatic.net/TpSOVr9J.png . My answer only showed the induced charges by proximity of other plates (NB: the outer charges would be much smaller under the assumptions used.) As for the remark by @Allure : the initial text and drawing clearly tell us that we have 10V between the outer plates both before and after the third one is inserted, so we are forced to assume that extra charge is provided, for instance by a battery, keeping $\Delta V$ fixed.

@JosBergervoet can you elaborate on why we have to make this assumption? Why can't the potential remain the same without extra charge?

Surface charge density is equal to the normal $E$-field component, which is in turn equal to the Voltage gradient in the gap(s). After the insertion there is less space left in the two gaps (only 9 cm) so the voltage gradient must be bigger to create the same 10V difference going from right to left. (NB: inside the inserted plate there is no voltage gradient, it is conductive). So we know the surface charges must become 11% bigger to accommodate this larger field strength.

Thanks for answer. Just to be sure: because the system requires a battery to maintain the voltage difference, it must attract the conductor while the conductor is being inserted, and therefore do work on the conductor, right?

@Allure How can we know that the potential difference is linear? Gauss as electric field is constant and equal to (-) potential gradient. Assume that the two potentials are fixed. Going from right to left requires 10J/C. If the distance moved in the electric field is reduced then the strength of the electric field must increase.

Indeed @Allure, the conductor is pulled in. so to say! But that would happen even if there was no battery, so the $\Delta V$ would drop from 10V to 9V while the field strength in the gap regions would remain the same. Energy to pull in the conductor in that case comes from the $E$-field which will vanish in the region where this third conductor is placed...

Come to think of it, it must, because inducing the electric charges on the conductor must require work.

One more question: if there's no battery, the potential difference between the two plates drops to 8V, right? If so, I assume the potentials of both plates change, but by how much? How can we calculate that?

If there is no battery $\Delta V$ would drop from 10V to 9V (not 8) and from far away the shape of the total system would still look the same, and it would still have the same total charge. So it would asymptotically have the same $1/r$ potential. This means that the potential averaged over the outside surfaces must remain the same, so 20V and 10V will change to 19.5V and 10.5V. (For a rigorous prove of that we could probably use the multipole expansion...)
